# "Minimizing" vertical VIM window splits

Tags: vim

I use horizontal and vertical window splits in religiously in VIM and up until recently, I enjoyed the comfort of two commands to effectively hide (or minimize) my horizontal splits. I set them up adding the following lines to my `.vimrc` file:

```
set winminheight=0
map <C-J> <C-W>j<C-W>_
map <C-K> <C-W>k<C-W>_
```

Hitting `Control-j` or `Control-k` navigates through horizontal splits by going up or down.  What I'd like to accomplish is the same thing for vertical splits by showing or hiding the left or right split using `Control-Shift-h` and `Control-Shift-l`; `h` moving to the left, `l` moving to the right.  I have tried the following with little to no success:

```
set winminwidth=0
map <S-C-L> 500<C-W>h<C-W>_
map <S-C-H> 500<C-W>l<C-W>_
```

The action would be similar to utilizing `Control-w-<` and `Control-w->`, only moving the vertical split *completely* to the left or write, not just one line at a time.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First up, you won't be able to use <S-C- (shift + control) in your code (see below).  But you can use the 'mapleader' as your "shift" and then use the  <C-h> and <C-l> like you want to.  Like this:

```
set winminwidth=0
nmap <Leader><C-h> <C-W>h500<C-W>>             
nmap <Leader><C-l> <C-W>l500<C-W>>
```

The common leader keys in vim are comma and back-slash:

```
:let mapleader = ","
```

But you'll find that this gets annoying to require 3 keystrokes for this, so you might as well just drop the control key stroke.  This way (if your leader is comma) you can just press ",h" and ",l" to go to the splits to your left and right:

```
set winminwidth=0
nmap <Leader>h <C-W>h500<C-W>>             
nmap <Leader>l <C-W>l500<C-W>>       

" (FTW) :D
```

...

A guy named Tony Chapman [answers](http://www.nabble.com/Maping-Ctrl-Shift-s-problems-td22918941.html) why you can't use control + shift:

> Vim maps its `Ctrl+printable_key`
>   combinations according to ASCII. This 
>   means that "`Ctrl+lowercase letter`" is
>   the same as the corresponding 
>   "`Ctrl+uppercase letter`" and that
>   `Ctrl+<key>` (where `<key>` is a printable
>   key) is only defined when `<key>` is in
>   the range 0x40-0x5F, a lowercase 
>   letter, or a question mark. It also
>   means that `Ctrl-[` is the same as  `Esc`,
>   `Ctrl-M` is the same as `Enter`, `Ctrl-I` is
>   the same as  `Tab`.
>
> So yes, `Ctrl-s` and `Ctrl-S` (i.e. `Ctrl-s`
>   and `Ctrl-Shift-s`) are the same to 
>   Vim. This is by design and is not
>   going to change.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
set winminwidth=0
map <S-C-L> <C-W>h<C-W>|
map <S-C-H> <C-W>l<C-W>|
```

This doesn't move a window completely to the left or right (that's `<C-W>H` and `<C-W>L`), it just moves the cursor to the left (or right) window and maximizes that window horizontally.

See [`:help CTRL-W_bar`](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v62/windows.html#CTRL-W_bar) for more.

Comment: help you mentioned doesn't work on my version of Vim 8.2

Answer (score 1):

> Crl-w 1 |

will minimize current window in Vim.