# Are CTRL-based key-bindings like `C-X` or `C-n` always case-insensitive?

Tags: bash, vim, terminology

> Are CTRL-based key-bindings like `C-X` or `C-n` always case-insensitive?

I sometimes see people write CTRL-based key-bidings in `vim` or `bash`, like `<c-n>`, `C-n`, `C-N`, or `CTRL-N`.

This has made me wonder, whether I can always ignore the case of the character following the control-character (`CTRL`)?

Please link to documentation, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262477/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+control+shift+keys

Comment: @Shuzheng: Look at the ASCII-table. All control keys (except control-backspaced) are mapped to the first 31 positions of the table. No room for distinction between upper- and lower case.

Comment: @user1934428 - how do I view the ASCII-table? I guess you are not referring to the canonical ASCII table found on Wikipedia, but a Vim specific one?

Comment: [ASCII table in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) is quite good. See the column `[c]` in the table to understand the `Control-character` mapping.

Comment: https://bestasciitable.com/

Comment: @Shuzheng : Since ASCII is a standard encoding for a character set, there is really only one. Alternatively, you can look at the [first 128 characters of UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which make up the same set.

Comment: @user1934428 - isn't control-backspace (`^H`) mapped to 0x08? So, it's not possible to write `Ctrl-Shift-a` (`=Ctrl-A`) to distinguish `Ctrl-a` and `Ctrl-A`?

Comment: @Shuzheng : And what ASCII code would Ctrl-a be mapped to? Don't confuse key press events (in which you can distinguish in theory with any set of keys pressed together) and corresponding character codes. If an application decides to detect certain key combinations, and the platform (OS, window manager) supports it, it can, if it wants to, distinguish between Ctrl-Shift-a, Ctrl-a and Ctrl-A.

Comment: @user1934428 - you are right, my confusion is what you describe, i.e. key press events and ASCII character codes. When I think more about it, it’s clear that the keyboard only has a single “a” character, and that it’s the OS that translates “Shift + a” into “A”. In reality, “A” doesn’t exist as a keyboard key. Am I right?

Comment: There can be several layers in passing keyboard events to an application, depending on the platform, and in any case this is not a programming question and hence StackOverflow is not the right case to ask this. So I suggest you post it in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).